# how to use the range function in underscore?

Tags: function, range, underscore.js

I have the following underscore code which loops through a json, I'm trying to figure out how to use the (range) function so that it only loops from 1 to 5 for example? Anyone know how this is done?

```
  <% _.each( looks, function( listItem, index ){ %> 
  <li>
  <a href="javascript:showDetailsView(<%= index %>)" class="look-btn" id="<%=listItem.id %>" data-look-id="<%= index %>">                       
  <img src="<%= listItem.image %>" alt="<%= listItem.id %>"/>
  <span class="seeLook"><localize id="13">See the Look</localize></span>
  </a>
  </li>
  <% }) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

`_.range` is probably not what you want, it's used to generate a list of integers and won't be of much help here.

Have a look at [`array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to work on a portion of an array:

```
<% _.each(looks.slice(1, 6), function( listItem, index ){ %> 
...
<% }) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map the integers in the range to the elements of your array:

```
<% _.chain(_.range(1,5)).map(function(t) { return looks[t]; }).each(function(listItem, index) { %>
...
<% }) %>
```

Or better use drop and take:

```
<% _.chain(looks).drop(1).take(5).each(function(listItem, index) { %>
...
<% }) %>
```